# I'm using a 3D std::vector and was wondering if using operator= on the top layer would copy over the data from the lower levels as well

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, operator-keyword

Assuming that A is empty, is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
using namespace std;

// Copy the contents of B into A
void copy(vector<vector<vector<int>>>& A, const vector<vector<vector<int>>>& B)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i)
    {
        vector<vector<int>> temp1;

        for(unsigned j = 0; j < B[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            vector<int> temp2;

            for(unsigned k = 0; k < B[i][j].size(); ++k)
            {
                temp2.pushback(B[i][j][k]);
            }

            temp1.push_back(temp2);
        }

        A.push_back(temp1);
    }
}
```

I was thinking that if the std::vector operator= was calling another operator= inside of itself, all of this would be happening recursively.  If that is the case, then it would be as simple as:

```
A = B;
```

I looked into vector.h but couldn't make heads or tails of it.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you *try* it? What were the results of your attempt?

Comment: I *think* you're asking if copying a `vector` will copy the elements that the vector contains.  Is that right?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: `A = B;` will make `A` identical to `B`.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you try it, you will see that it does indeed copy "recursively".

```
template <typename T>
using vec = std::vector<T>;
int main()
{
    std::vector<vec<vec<int>>> a = {{ {1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }};
    std::vector<vec<vec<int>>> b;
    b = a;
    std::cout << b; // assume overloaded for vector
}
```

Output: `1 2 3  4 5 6`

`operator=` just copies over all the elements of the other vector. Here's a snippet from how [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01593_source.html#l00165) implements it:

```
// ...
std::copy(__x._M_impl._M_start, __x._M_impl._M_start + size(),
          this->_M_impl._M_start);
// ...
```